# If else for string types in Business objects

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

How can I use if...else in Business Objects for strings? My problem is my query returns value in string which can contain duplicates. For duplicates, what I would like to do is find if I have duplicates or not and if found, just use one. I can do it for float type as like this: If [sales_rev]>1000 Then [high_rev] but if I do If [display_name]=['sth'] Then...., I always get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure based on your question, but it sounds like you're trying to assign a string value instead of compare it. Depending on your language, the most common operator to do boolean logic on strings is "==" while you just have a single "=" in your question so it'd probably be [display_name]==['sth'] based on what you stated.

Answer (score 2):

Try

If [display_name]="sth" Then....

without square brackets and with double quotes